# How to customize the WP admin default help contents

Tags: hooks, dashboard

I will be needing to customize the WP admin default help contents to be tailored specifically to a client in navigating his custom dashboard
[image: customizing the default WP admin dashboard help box]

What are the hooks and sample codes to use in restructuring its menu and the contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files to look at:
[**`wp-admin/includes/wp-current-screen.php`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-screen.php#L578) and [**`wp-admin/admin-header.php`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L228)

If we take a look at `admin-header.php` we can see that **`$current_screen->render_screen_meta();`** is the one responsible for rendering the contextual help on screens. It gets the global `$current_screen` which is set via `WP_Screen` class.

It has methods like `get_help_tabs`,`get_help_tab`,`add_help_tab`,`remove_help_tab`,`remove_help_tabs` , `set_help_sidebar` which sets and removes the tabs we see. Check the following code for sample.

```
/* 
We can hook into admin_head-{$page_hook}. admin_head fires after the 
default contextual help tabs have been added.
*/
add_action('admin_head-index.php', 'wpse_226724_add_help_tab');
function wpse_226724_add_help_tab () {

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    //checking whether we are on dashboard main page or not
    if ( $screen->id != 'dashboard' )
        return;

    //You can remove all default tabs using this
    //$screen->remove_help_tabs();

    //Adding tab with an id overview it gets replaced if tab is already available with same id
    $screen->add_help_tab( array(
        'id' => 'overview',
        'title' => __('WPSE'),
        'content' => '<p>'
        . __( 'Welcome to the WPSE community. Get a taste of WordPress!', 'text_domain' )
        . '</p>',
    ) );
}
```

We can use `get_help_tabs` to re-order the tabs. Default tabs available on main dashboard page (`wp-admin/index.php`) are:

- overview
- help-navigation
- help-layout
- help-content

And one sidebar help